# Monotouch Admob dll file size

Tags: xamarin.ios, admob, xamarin

I have downloaded Xamarin's binding for Admob from [Here](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleadmob)
and I see that GoogleAdMobAds.dll size is 16MB - is that actually the file I should use in my App? It's seems rather large and unreasonable.

Please advise :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native libGoogleAdModAds.a is 15MB, so this does looks quite normal actually.

Have in mind that libGoogleAdModAds.a contains code for 3 architectures (i386, arm7 and arm7s), and since you'll likely only use armv7 in your app (i386 is for when you're using the simulator - and when building for device you might be building for both armv7 and armv7s at the same time, but this is not very common), you'll probably only use ~5MB of those 15MB.

Comment: Is there something I need to do in order to re-size it and remove the unnecessary code or will it be done automatically in the build process?